# Return to app behavior after phone call different in native code than UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html), in order to make phone call from my app, I need to implement the following protocols:

**HTML link:**

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

**Native application URL string:**

```
tel:1-408-555-5555
```

However, upon completion of a phone call initiated from an HTML link inside a UIWebView, I am redirected right back to my application. But upon completion of a phone call made from a native application URL string, my iphone stays in the iphone's regular phone application, and if I want to return to my application I have to do so manually.

As far as I can tell from reading what others have said, there is no way to change this behavior.

**Here is my question:**

1. Is it true that it's impossible
   to return to an application after
   making a phone call from a native
   application URL string?
2. Would there be any downside to
   implementing a UIWebView instead of
   a UILabel in situations where I
   really wanted the user to be
   redirected back to my application
   after completing a phone call?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Behavior does differ between calling `-[UIApplication openURL:]` with a `tel:` URL, and clicking a link to the same URL in a `UIWebView`.
2. Using a `UIWebView` instead of a UILabel might have some downsides, but you don't have to actually display the `UIWebView` to get its `tel` URL handling behavior.  Instead, just load a `tel` URL request in an instance of UIWebView without adding it to your view hierarchy.

For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhoneCaller : NSObject
{
  @private
    UIWebView *webview;
}
- (void)callTelURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end

@implementation
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)callTelURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [webview release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: this is awesome, thanks! It would have never occurred to me to use the UIWebView just to make the phone call. Another added benefit is it creates an alert, which saves me a step.

Comment: it Worked for iOS 4.x devices .. have you guys tried to do this on iOS 5, apparently it stop working.. Thanks!

Comment: hey I am loading a web view which has phone number. Webview invokes the call alert on tapping the phone number link. But when user taps on cancel button on the calling screen, my app does not resume back. It displays black screen This happens in IOS5 devices. It was working properly in previous version devices. Please help..

Comment: You can also do [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"telprompt:0123456789"]; to get the prompt and return to your app afterwards.

Comment: User need to click "call" to continue. If there is a way to call automatically?

Answer (score 17):

The simplest way seems to be:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt:0123456789"]];
```

You will get a prompt and your app will regain focus after the call is finished.

Comment: Did you even test this? You're passing a string when a NSURL object is expected. This is not valid code and even throws a warning at compile time; needless to say it bombs at run-time.

Answer (score 10):

Allow me to simplify a bit. All you need is this little snippet:

```
UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:number-to-call"];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

which I got [here](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/bring-users-back-to-your-application-after-they-end-the-call/).

*Recently tested successfully on iOS 5.0.

Comment: when do you release the UIWebView? after the phone call ends and returns to your app? Wouldn't this leak as you've written it? or are you keeping the webview around for lifetime of app and using it for all calls?

Comment: @leolobato maybe You typed in the wrong number. (Must be without spaces, without " + "  etc... 

Works on all versions on my end.

Comment: Does this work on iOS 7?  I just tried it and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Adding the webview to my view works on iOS 7.1 
[self.view addSubview:callWebview];

Comment: Did anyone of you added the webview to the main view before the request? See my answer

Answer (score 4):

The Eric's Brotto method still works in 5.1. You have to add the webview to the main view before the loadRequest, like this:

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", escapedPhoneNumber]];
UIWebView *mCallWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init]  ;
[self.view addSubview:mCallWebview];
[mCallWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

(I added a phone number cleaner, to delete any non-number char that blocks this method)

Comment: It works perfectly! thanks a lot!!!
Is there any way to customise the popup message displaying just before the phone call?

Comment: Well, not using this way. You see, this is the "legal" (The App won't be rejected at the App Store) if you use this. There is another way: creating your popup and using the old way (calling the openURL using the sharedApplication) but instead of using the "tel" scheme, you have to change it to "telprompt". Notice that this functionality is undocumented, therefore, there is a chance to get your App rejected.