# after call summary app is not returning foreground in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to do phone call from my native iPhone app on button click in xcode 5.
After finishing the phone call, i'm getting the call summary display on my screen. After dismissing the call summary home screen is coming .

I want to return back to my app after finishing phone call.

I have tried with:

```
phnnoString=[@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:phnnoString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phnnoString]];
```

and 
`[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:phnnoString]];`

also
but whenever call summary page is coming after phone call, app is not returning to foreground.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You can find your answer here:::::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717780/iphone-call-another-phone-number-in-response-to-the-first-not-answering

Comment: @ParvendraSingh thats a totally different issue AFAICS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you dont control other apps, this isnt in your power. the OS should reactivate your app and in the past it did so I can only see this as being a BUG

Comment: Daij-Djan, thanks a lot. then i don't have waste my time to fix this.