# Re-opening the app after finishing a call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a button in my app to make a telephone call, and I need to returen to my app after call is finished.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you can ditch the button - you could use a webview http://stackoverflow.com/q/5317783/41116. It depends what is more important to you.

Comment: @Abizern I'm not sure how this is relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't be done. The user will have to open your app themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the user can make a phone call to another user, starting from your application, which closes said application, then what you are asking is simply impossible. The best you can do is have the application get into `suspended` mode. The user will need to get it back from the tray.

If for some reason your application has a button that calls the user (possibly by triggering some external server), then you should edit your question to be clearer... however, the user still needs to get your application back himself from `suspended` state.