# Return to my App after make a call

Tags: objective-c, ios

After my app make a call i would like to return to my app. When user hit "End" in call screen now he always see phone app. How to force app to return to my original app?

I make a call using:

```
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL]];
```

Comment: This [method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10683460/2521004) also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get back to your app after making a call from your app

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://phone number"];
[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.......

```
 UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];   
    NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber]
   [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that without jailbreaking.

Comment: I stand corrected—though there seems to be some trouble with this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317783